# Error "No service was found." while using Spring and Jetty

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am learning how to use spring based mvc with jetty with the help of this example, but again and again i am hitting this error : "No service was found.".
The logs are saying :

```
WARNING: Can't find the the request for  http://localhost:8080/rest/api/people's Observer`
```

I am following this tutorial : http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/going-rest-embedding-jetty-with-spring-and-jax-rs-apache-cxf.html

I am new and a newbie, and i have been trying for past one day, and not able to solve this, could someone guide me?

Comment: What url are you trying to hit? I can't understand from your warning message.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/rest/api/people?page=2

Comment: The tutorial you posted doesn't seem to have a mapping for that url.

Comment: But according to the documentation of the tutorial/rest/* is being mapped by jetty so anything after /rest/api/people should be mapped to a url right?

Comment: Yes, that maps the servlet, but not the path. Unless you've modified it, the `PeopleRestService` class only serves PUT AND GET requests to `/people`.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/rest/api/people 
also throws me "No service was found." both by using curl or by hitting the browser. Could u suggest a url mapping which should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error in mapping ""rest//Api/people". Notice the double //